# Create a variable if another variable is null in python

Tags: python, pandas

I would create a variable if another variable is null.

`

```
if df['var_1'].isnull():
     df['var_2']==1
else:
     df['var_2']==0
```

`
I know, this code is not true, it is to make you understand the problem.

Can someone help me?
Thanks

Comment: for variable assignment, make sure you use "=" instead of "==". "==" is used for comparison only, while "=" is used to assign a value to a variable

Comment: Do you call the pandas DataFrame column a variable in a "SAS" meaning of this word?

Answer (score 0):

If this is pandas, we should try to stick to pandas/numpy for this type of thing.

```
# For your specific case:
df['var_2'] = df['var_1'].notna().astype(int)

# A more generalized approach:
df['var_2'] = np.where(df['var_1'].isna(), 'if true', 'if false')
```

Comment: `df['var_2'] = df['var_1'].notna().astype(int)` ? ;)

Comment: @mozway Updated to include the suggestion, I don't like using anything other than True/False for binary options :')